Transaction simulation failed: This account may not be used to pay transaction fees
Hi I'm getting this when trying to run anchor deploy on devnet & testnet while testing got the following error.
Error: Account allocation failed: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: This account may not be used to pay transaction fees 
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.

I have 16 SOLs on devnet

Anchor.toml

[toolchain]

[features]
resolution = true
skip-lint = false

[programs.localnet]
test = "HkP6uxB55uMYkfNAT2A2bjpZwRZz64f2nxta8mtnz4mM"

[registry]
url = "https://api.apr.dev"

[provider]
cluster = "devnet"
wallet = "~/.config/solana/id.json"

[scripts]
test = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts"


[test]
startup_wait = 10000
shutdown_wait = 10000

[test.validator]
bind_address = "0.0.0.0"
url = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
ledger = ".anchor/test-ledger"
rpc_port = 8899

[[test.validator.clone]]
address = "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"


lib.rs

#[program]
mod customSPL {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize_token(
        ctx: Context<InitializeToken>,
        metadata: InitTokenParams,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        // Initialize burn state with our tokenomics parameters
        let burn_state = &mut ctx.accounts.burn_state;
        burn_state.total_supply = 99_999_999_999_999;
        burn_state.burned_amount = 0;
        burn_state.burn_limit = (burn_state.total_supply as f64 * 0.65) as u64;
        burn_state.mint = ctx.accounts.mint.key();
        burn_state.minted_amount = 0; // Start with 0 minted tokens

        // Create metadata for the token
        let token_data = DataV2 {
            name: metadata.name,
            symbol: metadata.symbol,
            uri: metadata.uri,
            seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
            creators: None,
            collection: None,
            uses: None,
        };

        let seeds = &["mint".as_bytes(), &[ctx.bumps.mint]];
        let signer = [&seeds[..]];

        // Create metadata accounts through Metaplex
        let metadata_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
            CreateMetadataAccountsV3 {
                metadata: ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
                mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                mint_authority: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                update_authority: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                payer: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
            },
            &signer,
        );

        create_metadata_accounts_v3(metadata_ctx, token_data, false, true, None)?;

        msg!("TOKEN initialized successfully. Ready for minting.");
        Ok(())
    }
[...]


It turns out that a system program did not own my account. I don't have any explanation for this behaviour at the moment. I have used solana-keygen new to generate the account. The way I solved it was by important a phantom wallet keypair.
